# Nodelist vs Node vs Element

Tags: xml, nodes, element, nodelist

If you had an XML file like this

```
<Users>
  <student>
    <firstname> Chris </firstname>
    <lastname> Smith </lastname>
    <address> 1313 Mockingbird Lane </address>
    <phone> 555-1313 </phone>
  </student>
  <student>
    <firstname> John </firstname>
    <lastname> Doe </lastname>
    <address> 1526 Bluebird Way </address>
    <phone> 555-8324 </phone>
  </student>
</Users>
```

Then would...

1. Users be considered a Nodelist?
2. Student be considered an Element or a Nodelist? The student tag contains more tags, but it is also the child of the tag Users. So would this be an Element or Nodelist?
3. The value "John" be a Node?

If I am mistaken in one of these, can you please tell me how to find out the difference between a node, element, and nodelist?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are mixing some loosely defined terminology, and it's important to separate general concepts from specific meanings in the context of XML.

In XML an "element" is a `<tag>...</tag>` and that definition can be applied recursively to nested tags (elements can contain elements).

`Node` and `NodeList` are general concepts.  A `Node` is, roughly, a distinct object with some internal state. The name `Node` implies that the object can be or is a member of some collection, often but not always a list.

A `NodeList` is just a linear list of nodes. There are other types of collection that can contain nodes, such as a `Map` or `Graph` or `Tree`.

In your example:

`Users` is an XML element. It is also conceptually a node in the XML tree.  It contains `student` elements so it is also a collection, and since the elements are arranged linearly, it is also a node list.

A `student` is an XML element, and conceptually it is also a `node` in the list of students.

The `firstname` tag (and everything inside it) is also an XML element and a node in the XML tree of nodes.

The value `John` is not an element as defined by XML. It is a `text node` contained in `firstname`.